# How to load my site without index.php directly

Tags: php, html, pageload

I have a problem. When I go on my site: http://nextgenfocus.com/, content is not properly loaded and I need to add index.php so that all content is displayed. I would like that when that when I run my site in the URL without index.php, it loads directly the index.php without that I need to do it manually.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index.php") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Home</title>
        <?php } ?>
       <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "downloads") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Downloads</title>
        <?php } ?>
       <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "help") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Help</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("top_bar.php");?>
        <?php include("container.php");?>
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do that with `.htaccess`

Comment: are you using codeigniter?

Comment: How can I do exactly, please?

Comment: You should ideally set this at the web-server configuration level e.g. with Apache in the `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file .htaccess in your home dir. Put this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php [QSA]
```

And `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP to get the url.

Comment: Where I place $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Comment: It is just holding the url for when you need some information out of it. If you want to know what it holds use: var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']). I read in the other question that you can't remove the .txt from .htacces. This will also not work if you can't remove it. Use a text editor to remove it.

Comment: Code doesn't work and I can't seem to fix the problem. Even people below have tried, but I have an error on the server or nothing is displayed.

Comment: Do you want my FTP access?

Comment: Instal FileZilla in that ftp program you can change it to .htaccess

Comment: Yes, I have, but can't fix the problem. http://prntscr.com/47p5ms and in my FileZilla server: http://prntscr.com/47p5q2

Comment: If you can send it somewere privatly. I can look at it. Don't know if it's allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text file named `.htaccess` that contains the following rule, and then place this file at the root of your server.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

So whenever someone visits your webpage at `www.example.com`, your server try to display the content of `index.php` to her, if such file doesn't exists, your server will try `index.html`, and then `index.htm` and so on.

Comment: Do you currently have the `.htaccess` file at the root of your server of ` nextgenfocus.com`? If so, have you included the `DirectoryIndex` rule in it and is it the only rule in the file?

Comment: Yes, look: http://prntscr.com/47ox6i and I put it to the root of my server: http://prntscr.com/47oxf5 and when I remove the .txt of the .htaccess, I get the error.

Comment: Just to double confirm, `.htaccess` is the **fullname** of the file, there is no hidden file extension. Please note that it only works if the fullname of the config file is called `.htaccess`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but impossible to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you having problem with renaming the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

.htaccess should go into same folder as your CI’s index.php file.

or try this one..

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

Its possible that .htaccess is not enabled on your site. If you are hosting it yourself, it's easy enough to fix; open your httpd.conf in a text editor, and locate this  section..

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
#
```

..locate the line that reads..

```
AllowOverride None
```

..and change it to..

```
AllowOverride All
```

Restart Apache.

I have this reference [**.htaccess**](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess.php?page=all)

Comment: The same... Look: http://nextgenfocus.com/ I do not have the title that I have set to index.php and it is not linked. I get the server error.

Comment: try adding this RewriteBase /yoursite/ on .htaccess code

Comment: No, I just created the .htaccess file with the data that you gave me above.

Comment: on my window, the .htaccess set to be invisible and then I disable operating system's invisible file functions. I just edited the .htaccess

Comment: Do you want my FTP access to see?

Comment: After properly completing what you said, I still have this error: http://prntscr.com/47p8zc

Answer (score 0):

This is my WAMP .htaccess file, work hurt trying it, won't ya? :D

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: When I put the .htaccess file in my FileZilla server, I need to remove the .txt? Nothing works.

Comment: Do you want my FTP access?

Comment: use .htaccess only, no extensions (no .htaccess.txt etc.）

Comment: if can, sure, it will be more convenient. If you trust me :D

Comment: Impossible to fix the problem. :(